# OpenFoam: Cannot find blockMeshDict file in polyMesh folder

Tags: terminal, command-prompt, paraview, openfoam, cfdata

Using the command terminal, I try to access the blockMeshDict file from the docker. I access the cavity folder, constant folder, then polyMesh folder. I know the blockMeshDict file is supposed to be within the polyMesh folder, but when I enter 'ls' to view what the polyMesh folder contains, it shows files "points", "owner", "boundary", "faces" and "neighbor", as shown in the first screenshot I uploaded.

I then tried another path by first going into the tutorials folder, which is shown in the second screenshot I uploaded. From tutorials, I went to incompressible -> icoFoam -> cavity -> constant -> polyMesh. But the polyMesh folder only contained "TransportProperties" as shown in the screenshot.

In short, please help me find the blockMeshDict file. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7I8M.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6120V.png)

Answer (score 2):

`blockMeshDict` moved to the `system` directory in V3.0 so you should find it in there.

You can also use the `find` command from within the case directory to locate *"missing"* files, something like this:

```
    find . -name blockMeshDict
```